Does there exist a set $A$ of no finite Hausdorff dimension?
I started reading Hausdorff measure so, I have some questions regarding Hausdorff measures, which I tried to look into some standard reference book for answers but could not find. I am mostly following Folland's "Modern Technique in Analysis".

Does there exist any set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that its Hausdorff dimension is strictly greater than $n$? I feel such a measure exists for example if we take $A=\mathbb{R}$ whose $H^{1}(A)=\infty$ clearly and $H^{2}(A)=0$. Therefore by Proposition 11.19 (Folland) the dimension should lie between (1,2). But I want to confirm this that the Hausdorff-dimension of infinite line segment exists really and it is fractional.

And also does there exist a set $A$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ such that its Hausdorff dimension is not finite? I think some pathological examples serves this purpose but I tried to solve it, could not get any idea?



In 1) you use two calculations $H^1(A)=\infty$ and $H^2(A)=0$ to conclude that the dimension should lie between $(1,2)$.
But that conclusion is not correct, all you can conclude so far is that the Hausdorff dimension lies in the closed interval $[1,2]$.
Further investigation shows that for any subset $A \subset \mathbb R^1$ and for any $d > 1$ we have $H^d(A)=0$ and therefore the Hausdorff dimension of $A$ is $\le 1$. And if furthermore $H^1(A) > 0$, for instance if $A=\mathbb R$ or more generally if $A$ has nonzero Lebesgue measure, it follows that the Hausdorff dimension of $A$ equals $1$.

But $H^{1}$ is upto scaling is same as lebesgue measure, therefore the one dimensional Hausdroff measure of infinite line $\mathbb{R}$ is infinity. And sorry I neved mentioned $H^2(A)=2$, i wrote 0 instead of 2. @Lee Mosher

And the definition of dimension suggest that under that dimensional Hausdroff measure of $A$ is a finite positive(>0) real number in folland's book. @Lee Mosher

Basically my question what is the Hausdroff dimension of real number?

Basically my question what is the Hausdroff dimension of real number? --- Hausdorff dimension is defined for SUBSETS of a given ambient set $({\mathbb R}^n$ in your case), and a real number is NOT a subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ (even when $n=1).$ Maybe you mean what is the Hausdorff dimension of a subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ consisting of a single point (i.e. a singleton set)? If so, then the Hausdorff dimension is zero (even when $n=1).$ (moments later) I read "of real number" as "of a real number". Maybe you meant to write "of the set of real numbers"?

I rewrote my answer to address your latest question.

Yes, I noticed that and posted an addition to my comment virtually to the same second you wrote about the possible grammatical error. In reading what was written, I mentally filled in the article "a" without realizing it.

@LeeMosher the same thing is true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ it seems. But how to prove in that case $H^{n+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^n)=0$? I can't make any such cover. For real line it is easy to make but higher dimension I could not show this.
